# Getting Not Found 404 error when tryin to deploy springboot WAR to Wildfly on local with docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jboss, dockerfile, wildfly

I am trying to deploy springboot API to Wildfly on local using docker container but facing issues.

Docker File:

```
FROM mechero/wildfly:13.0.0-openjdk-10

# Expose the default's application port
EXPOSE 8080

# Copy the war file to the deployments folder
COPY target/example.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/example.war
```

Under application controller, I have the following:

```
@PostMapping(value="/abc/def",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public function {}
```

I used the following command via CL:

```
docker build -t wildfly-springboot-app .
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it wildfly-springboot-app
```

Now I tried the URL: **http://localhost:8080/** and I was able to see Welcome to WILDFLY page.
But when I appended my application details to the URL (http://localhost:8080/example/abc/def/, I got "Not Found" error. I am not sure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you get the logs out of Wildfly to validate that the war deployed correctly?

Comment: get the logs, it seems you're deploying the application correctly but then you're having a run-time error perhaps.